# If the Dawn probe visits a third asteroid after Ceres and Vesta, which asteroid could it visit?

Tags: asteroid, dawn-mission

The Dawn mission was supposed to end after its rendezvous with Ceres, but now, reports say that [the Dawn team has asked NASA to extend the mission to visit a third asteroid](http://www.universetoday.com/128547/dawn-just-wants-make-probes-look-bad/).

There’s only a small amount of propellant left, so there’s only a limited selection of possible destinations for Dawn at this point.

[image: Dawn probe]

Chris Russell, of the University of California, Los Angeles, is the principal investigator for the Dawn mission. [He told New Scientist,](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2085288-nasas-dawn-probe-may-visit-third-asteroid-after-ceres-and-vesta/) “As long as the mission extension has not been approved by NASA, I’m not going to tell you which asteroid we plan to visit,” he says. “I hope a decision won’t take months.”

So I ask this question to the stackexchange community: can you make any educated guesses about this "third asteroid"?

Comment: This question seems answerable. We should be able to calculate what asteroids are in range of Dawn based on the remaining fuel.

Comment: I believe it was recently decided that Dawn will not be traveling to any other asteroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dawn's potential target was asteroid 145 Adeona:

> On April 20, 2016, New Scientist announced that the Dawn team had sent
>   NASA a proposal for an extended mission. According to the report, the
>   spacecraft retains enough xenon fuel to break Ceres orbit and reach a
>   third asteroid.[123] In July 2016, NASA rejected the proposal because
>   remaining in orbit around Ceres has the potential to provide more
>   significant science discoveries than a flyby of 145 Adeona in May
>   2019.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_%28spacecraft%29#Mission_conclusion

Comment: Sounds like there wouldn't have been enough fuel to go into orbit around 145 Adeona, just a flyby.